# Unable to stop form from submitting with empty inputs

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I am unable to stop the form from submitting when any of the inputs are blank.  It's not erroring out, but it's also not stopping the submit.  I have the function being called in the form submit input.  It is under the onClick call.

JS File

```
function stopSubmit(){
  var inDay = document.getElementById(indate).value;
  var inType = document.getElementById(intype).value;
  var inAmount = document.getElementById(inamount).value;
  if (inDay == "") {
    alert("Please select a date");
    return false;
  }
  if (inType == "Select One"){
    alert("Please select a frequency");
    return false;
  }
  if (inAmount == ""){
    alert("Please enter an amount");
    return false;
  }
  else {
    alert("Your form was submitted");
  }
}
```

HTML File

```
<td>
          <input type="submit" name="submitincome" value="submit" onclick="stopSubmit()">
        </td>
```

Comment: Before `return false` add  `e.preventDefault()` also pass the event object: `stopSubmit(e)`

Comment: I'd put it as the first statement in that function.

Comment: Normally I would too, but the `else` needs to be submitted at the end of function

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.  I failed to mention that my else is not even working.  I tried adding what you mentioned, but nothing seems to be working.  It seems like the function is not even being called.  Even not having the e.preventDefault() and stopSubmit(e) should not keep the else from creating the alert, correct?

Comment: @micogg see edited answer to save yourself a headache.

Answer (score 3):

## Edit

Use the `required` attribute and you won't even need any JavaScript. See demo 2. for a functioning demo see this [**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/7gS4oF1tyynVXEjlvfDq/)

---

### OLD

Before each `return false` add `e.preventDefault()`

### Demo (Does not function due to SO security measures)

```js
function stopSubmit(e) {
  var inDay = document.getElementById(indate).value;
  var inType = document.getElementById(intype).value;
  var inAmount = document.getElementById(inamount).value;
  if (inDay == "") {
    alert("Please select a date");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  if (inType == "Select One") {
    alert("Please select a frequency");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  if (inAmount == "") {
    alert("Please enter an amount");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Your form was submitted");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>

  <td>
    <input type="submit" name="submitincome" value="submit" onclick="stopSubmit()">
  </td>

</form>
```

### Demo 2 Use the required attribute

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    input {
      display: block
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <form id='inform' action='http://httpbin.org/post' method='post'>
    <input id='indate' name='indate' required>
    <input id='intype' name='intype' required>
    <input id='inamount' name='inamount' required>

    <input type="submit">


  </form>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried adding the preventdefault and it still had no effect.  I failed to say that the "else" is not even creating an alert saying the form was submitted.  From the code you see (including the preventdefault), does it seem like the issue may be in a different part of my code than what I pasted?

Comment: Your'e welcome. Is your submit button inside a form element or does it have a form attribute associated to a form?

Comment: @micogg If you use the `required` attribute, you don't have to use JavaScript. See edit and demo 2

Comment: <form method="post" action="ThisFile.php">
      <table>
      <tr>
      <td>
        <!--input-->
      </td>
      <td>
        <!--input-->
        </td>
        <td>
          <!--input-->
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="submit" name="submitname" value="submit" onclick="stopSubmit()">
        </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </form>

Comment: Sorry, I thought that would paste better.. The submit button is inside of the form element I believe.

Comment: @micogg forget about using JavaScript for that function, the HTML attribute [`required`](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html) **works exactly** how you want your `stopSbmit()` function to work. Take a look at this [**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/7gS4oF1tyynVXEjlvfDq/)

Comment: That works.  Thanks, I'll keep working on the function for that at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to see where you doing the mistake, `document.getElementById()` takes in a string as the parameter but you happen to be passing an undefined variable

```
function stopSubmit(){
  var inDay = document.getElementById('indate').value;
  var inType = document.getElementById('intype').value;
  var inAmount = document.getElementById('inamount').value;
  if (inDay === "") {
  alert("Please select a date");
  return false;
}
if (inType == "Select One"){
  alert("Please select a frequency");
  return false;
}
if (inAmount === ""){
  alert("Please enter an amount");
  return false;
}
else {
  alert("Your form was submitted");
}
}
```